# Proving equality is reflexive in Q0 (equality-based formulation of type theory)

Tags: logic, type-theory

The SEP has a nice article on Church's Type Theory, and in it they discuss Peter Andrews' equality-based formulation of type theory called Q0:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/#ForBasEqu

The first thing I'd like to do in an equality-based system is prove equality is an equivalence class. Symmetry and Transitivity seem like they can be trivially proven using the rule of inference.

But I'm struggling to see how reflexivity (`∀x[x = x]`) can be proven with the given axioms.

Answer (score 0):

Axiom 4 states that $(\lambda y_\alpha.y_\alpha)x_\alpha= x_\alpha$. Since you've proven symmetry and transitivity, this immediately gives reflexivity. (There are many other terms you can use that would beta reduce to $x_\alpha$.)